# How STL containers suppose to handles assignment operator

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

I would like to understand sematic specified behind ie copy assignment operator for Vector or UnorderedMap. Is this somewhere stated what will be done on this action (or is it implementation defined) ? Ie. if it will fire copy assignment on stored data or ? Simple program show's that in case of copy assignment STL seems to do copy construction + destruction of old entries.
Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

struct TypeA {
TypeA() {
  
}
 TypeA(const TypeA& a)
  {
    std::cout << "Copy ctor " <<std::endl;
  }
  
  TypeA(TypeA&& a)
  {
    std::cout << "move ctor " <<std::endl;
  }
  
  TypeA& operator=(const TypeA& a)
  {
    std::cout << "Copy assigment " <<std::endl;
    return *this;
  }
  
   TypeA& operator=( TypeA&& a)
  {
    std::cout << "move assigment " <<std::endl;
     return *this;
  }
  
  ~  TypeA() {
    std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl;
  }
};


int main() 
{
    std::vector<TypeA> bla;
    bla.emplace_back(TypeA{});
    bla.emplace_back(TypeA{});
    bla.emplace_back(TypeA{});
    
     std::vector<TypeA> bla2;
    
    bla2.emplace_back(TypeA{});
    bla2.emplace_back(TypeA{});
    
    std::cout << "Start TEST" <<std::endl;
    bla2 = bla;
       std::cout << "END TEST" <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

result in

```
...
Start TEST
Copy ctor 
Copy ctor 
Copy ctor 
dtor
dtor
...
END TEST
```

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D): "[...] the memory owned by `*this` may be reused when possible. In any case, the elements originally belonging to `*this` may be either destroyed or replaced by element-wise copy-assignment."

Comment: @molbdnilo so do I get this right that there is no precise requirement on it and the only contract is that *this will have same values as the other after assignment and impl can do whatever it takes ? Sorry but explanation there is a bit unclear and shady to me

Comment: Yes. In general, an implementation is expected to do the most efficient thing while preserving exception safety. If you make `bla` bigger than `bla2` you will probably see assignments followed by destruction of the unwanted elements of `bla`. (No resizing is necessary in that case.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks ! Do you know by any chance if same will hold for _map containers? There I always also see copy construction, but still I understand same thing: ".. In general, an implementation is expected to do the most efficient thing while preserving exception safety..."

Comment: It doesn't even "hold" for vectors, but is an implementation detail. I have never needed to care about this in 25 years, and you probably won't either.

Comment: For all the gory details you should read [the standard](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard).

Comment: Side note: "would like to understand sematic specified behind ie copy assignment operator for Vector or UnorderedMap" - there are no such types in the standard library. Remember; C++ is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the copy assignment operator replaces the contents with a copy of the contents of the source object.

The behavior that you encountered in your test results from a misunderstanding of the sentence "the memory may be reused", which suggests that the memory may require to be reallocated when the number of elements to be copied from the source container is greater than the capacity of the target container. Other containers may have stricter rules: for example, the `std::unordered_map` container may require a reallocation when the load factor is pushed beyond its upper limit.

Notwithstanding, the capacity of the `bla2` object, which has been increased by only one unit at a time due to the implementation that handles the growth factor, is not sufficient to contain the elements of the `bla` object. For this reason, the memory of `bla` can not be reused and then a reallocate operation is performed. Specifically, the elements are copy-constructed into the new array (a move-construct operation is not performed as the `Type` move constructor is not garanteed to be non-throwing) and the elements in the old memory are destroyed.